# Cast two interfaces that have same methods but different namespaces to one generic class/interface

Tags: java, logging, interface

I have to different logging services that implement the exact same methods, however, they have different namespaces.

```
package com.first.namespace
public interface loggerA
{
 void info();
 void warn();
 void debug();
 void error();
}

package com.second.namespace
public interface loggerB
{
 void info();
 void warn();
 void debug();
 void error();
}
```

and I have a DB class that must use a logger.

```
public class DB{

private MyCustomLogger logger;
public DB(MyCustomLogger log){
logger = log;

}
}
```

And finally I have two different services:

```
public class serviceA{

@inject 
private LoggerA logger;

private DB myDB;

public serviceA(){
       myDB = new myDB(??); // How can I pass/cast the logger properly here.???
}

}


public class serviceB{

@inject 
private LoggerB logger;

private DB myDB;

public serviceB(){
       myDB = new myDB(??); // How can I pass/cast the logger properly here.???
}
```

What is the best solution to pass/cast each of those different loggers properly to myDB class that has a unique logger parameter?

Note that I have not created yet `MyCustomLogger`, I am still searching the best way to do write this class or to get rid of it, if there is a better solution.

Comment: Why do you need two interfaces that are exactly the same?

Comment: You can't do that. There is no relationship between the two logger interfaces, therefore the 'DB' class cannot be written to treat them interchangeably. (You could double up on all logging code in DB but that would be a terrible idea).

Comment: I know that it is not easily possible, however, unfortunately, I'm developing two different plugins that give me (with inject) two different loggers interfaces as shown in my example. and I need to use a db class that should use a logger for debugging purposes.

Comment: You need an [Adapter](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/adapter).

Comment: Agree with @jaco0646, You should create your own Logger implementation (to be used by `myDb`) and adapt both Logger interfaces to it. The proper way would be that LoggerA and LoggerB both extends a common interface.